# getting back solution from tfs

Tags: c#, tfs, tfvc

I'm new to TFS, I have a **big** project that I have made I tried to add it to TFS, but since than I have a weird stuff I guess it's because I'm not familiar with TFS.

How do I fix the following:

[image]

I mean where is all the regular `.cs` files, please help me to recover my big project.

Comment: I fixed it via `View--->solution explorer` and that's it, thanks anyway

Comment: You can add your answer and mark it as accepted answer (to help other users with the same issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it via `View--->solution explorer` and that's it.